# lmodern font - caption "font-style"

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I am using the lmodern font-package and noticed, that the font on the chapter and section captions (also table of contents) slightly differs from the main document-title etc.

I don't know if this is a good style and I just should get used to it, but what I awaited is the same style for the normal text and the captions.

[image: example]

Comment: that is the default setting of the KOMA classes and can be changed, if really needed, by setting the KOMA macros. See manual.

Comment: alright - so then I will check the manual. thanks for advice.

Comment: BTW: it is a good style, that's why it is included in KOMA-Script ...

Comment: Thank you - that's always nice to know and why I am asking this.